# Assert Test wont pass, just - Selenium issues

Tags: java, selenium, assert

I am currently conducting the following piece of automated cod. It works automatically but when it gets to the key assert test, it does not work. Any suggestions why my code is failing

```
package Key;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.Assert;





public class KeyEvent {
    
    @Test
    
public void keyEventTest() throws Exception {
        
        
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/key_presses");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        
        
        Actions action= new Actions (driver);
        action.sendKeys(Keys.SPACE).build().perform();
        String text = driver.findElement(By.id("result")).getText();
        System.out.println(text);
    Assert.assertEquals (text,"You entered : Space");
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Is it as simple as a typo?

Asserts are case sensitive & white space sensitive.

Compare what the application produces manually to what you expect:

- You have: `You entered : Space`
- My Chrome has `You entered: SPACE`

This is how mine looks:

[image: SPACE]

Comment: Havent tried it. But could this be why my test isnt producing the wonderful shade of green lol

Comment: That sorted it. Thanks